# Excel multiple V look up formula pasted to used range by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to summarise data from sheet5 into sheet9.
Sheet 5 has multiple rows of data with yearly and monthly data.
Sheet 9 has a list of ID's and Company names. No duplicates.
The matching ID is in column A of both sheets.
I need to summarise the data in sheet5 , by year , month and if there is any data added in sheet5 columns CS:DD.
I wanted to run a VBA code , that ask for year with an input box. Then based on that year. example if year was 2018
Match Column A sheet9 to Column A Sheet5
If Column D sheet5 = 2018 and Column E sheet5 = M1 and sheet5.Range("CS:DD") contains atleast 1 non blank cell. Then in column D on sheet5. Add yes. Else No.  Column D would be for Jan (M1) Month 1. 
Then same formula pasted in Column E based on if Column E = M2 , this would be for Feb , replicate this up to Dec.

I have first of all tried searching multiple VBLook Up formulas , but could not find a solution

```
Sub Progress()
Dim x
Dim y
Dim tabl As ListObject
Set tabl = Sheet5.ListObjects(1)
Dim orgid As String
Dim yearchoice As Variant
yearchoice = InputBox("Enter year to filter by format is 2019", "Select Year")

Dim lrow1, lrow6
tabl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
tabl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=yearchoice
lrow1 = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrow6 = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lrow6
orgid = Sheet6.Range("A" & x).Value

For y = 2 To lrow1

If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M1" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("D" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M2" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("E" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M3" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("F" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M4" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("G" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M5" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("H" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M6" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("I" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M7" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("J" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M8" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("K" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M9" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("L" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M10" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("M" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M11" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("N" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
If Sheet5.Range("A" & y).Value = orgid And Sheet5.Range("E" & x).Value = "M12" And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet5.Range("CS" & y & ":DD" & y).Value) > 0 Then Sheet6.Range("O" & x).Value = "YES": GoTo found
found:

Next y
Next x
End Sub
```

This code froze on me , I was told a formula pasted in would be quicker

Comment: `found:` should be outside the loop. Or abandon it. Use `Exit For` instead. That is my take in freezing. As for your problem, I'm just guessing since we don't have sample data, but have you tried `Pivot Table`? I just thought you don't need VBA for this.

Comment: Why not use the `Select Case` approach here, saves a ton or redundant code.

Comment: where is the select case code please